# componentWillReceiveProps vs getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

What exactly componentWillReceiveProps and getDerivedStateFromProps are subtle question for me. Because, I just came across to an issue while using getDerivedStateFromProps:

```
// Component 
state = {
  myState: []
}

// Using this method works fine:

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    myState: nextProps.myPropsState
  })
}

// But using this method will cause the checkboxes to be readonly:

static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps,prevProps) {
  const { myPropsState: myState } = nextProps
  return {
    myState
  }
}

// And here's checkbox
<input type="checkbox" id={`someid`} 
 onChange={(e) => this.handleMethod(e, comp.myState)} 
 checked={myState.indexOf(comp.myState) > -1} />
```

**React version: 16.4.1**

Comment: The parameters passed to [`getDerivedStateFromProps ()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) are the current `props` and `state` and not `nextProps` and `prevProps`. It should return the next state depending on the current state and props. Please carefully read the docs at least.

Comment: that shouldn't matter here however, parameter name can be anything we wish but I just wrote to compare will receive props. Further, I'm here to why checkboxes are readonly when I use derived state?

Comment: How does it help to compare them by naming its parameters with something that they aren't representing? Also [unconditionally updating state from props is considered an anti-pattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I resolved my issue. It was a painful debugging:

```
// Child Component

// instead of this
// this.props.onMyDisptach([...myPropsState])

// dispatching true value since myPropsState contains only numbers
this.props.onMyDispatch([...myPropsState, true])
```

This is because, I have two conditions: 1) on checkbox change (component) 2) on reset button pressed (child component)

I was needing to reset the states when reset button is pressed. So, while dispatching state to the props for reset button, I used a boolean value to know it's a change from the reset. You may use anything you like but need to track that.

Now, here in the component, I found some hints to the differences between componentWillReceiveProps and getDerivedStateFromProps after debugging the console output.

```
// Component
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    const { myPropsState: myState } = props
    // if reset button is pressed
    const true_myState = myState.some(id=>id===true)
    // need to remove true value in the store
    const filtered_myState = myState.filter(id=>id!==true)
    if(true_myState) {
      // we need to dispatch the changes to apply on its child component
      // before we return the correct state
      props.onMyDispatch([...filtered_myState])
      return {
        myState: filtered_myState
      }
    }
    // obviously, we need to return null if no condition matches
    return null
  }
```

**Here's what I found the results of the console output:**

- getDerivedStateFromProps logs immediately whenever props changes
- componentWillReceiveProps logs only after child propagates props changes
- getDerivedStateFromProps doesn't respond to the props changes ( I meant for the dispatch changes as in the example code)
- componentWillReceiveProps responds to the props changes
- Thus, we needed to supply the changes to child component while using getDerivedStateFromProps.

The process of pasting true value in the state I require because getDerivedStateFromProps handle all the changes unlike componentWillReceiveProps handles only the child component dispatches the changes to the props.

By the way, you may use custom property to check if it is changed and update the value if getDerivedStateFromProps but for some reason I have to tweak this technique.

There might be some confusion on my wording but I hope you'll get it.

Comment: Elements in lists should usually be of the same type. Also you iterate through the entire list just to find that value. Note that you do that **on every render** while in probably 99% of the cases there is no `boolean` inside. Why not just pass another prop along with the reset that you check if it changed? E.g. an auto-incrementing counter like it is suggested in the react blog post? This will be much more efficient, easier and less error prone. You wrote that "`getDerivedStateFromProps` doesn't respond to the props changes". This is not true. It responds to every change in props or state.

Comment: ah, this is bit confusing to others. what i wanted to say is that using componentWillReceiveProps no need to dispatch but using derived required me to dispatch for the changes. and i agree with your suggestion, but for some reason i used the above method.

Answer (score 7):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is not a direct alternative to `componentWillReceiveProps`, purely because of the fact that its called after every update, whether its the change in state or change in props or re-render of parent.

**However whatever is the case, simply returning the state from `getDerivedStateFromProps` is not the right way, you need to compare the state and props before returning the value. Else with every update the state is getting reset to props and the cycle continues**

As per the **[docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)**

> `getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked right before calling the render
>   method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should
>   return an object to update the state, or `null` to update nothing.
>
> This method exists for rare use cases where the state depends on
>   changes in props over time. For example, it might be handy for
>   implementing a `<Transition>` component that compares its previous and
>   next children to decide which of them to animate in and out.
>
> Deriving state leads to verbose code and makes your components
>   difficult to think about. Make sure you’re familiar with simpler
>   alternatives:
>
> If you need to **perform a side effect** (for example, data fetching
>   or an animation) in response to a change in props, use
>   `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle instead.
>
> If you want to **re-compute some data only when a prop changes**, use
>   a `memoization` helper instead.
>
> If you want to **“reset” some state when a prop changes**, consider
>   either making a component `fully controlled` or `fully uncontrolled
>   with a key instead`.

**P.S.** Note that the arguments to getDerivedStateFromProps are `props` and `state` and not `nextProps` and `prevProps`

To get into more details,

In order to make changes based on props change, we need to store prevPropsState in state, in order to detect changes. A typical implementation would look like

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // Note we need to store prevPropsState to detect changes.
    if (
      props.myPropsState !== state.prevPropsState
    ) {
      return {
        prevPropsState: state.myState,
        myState: props.myPropsState
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still I'm facing same issue.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Please read [this official blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) on how to handle such situations. Using `getDerivedStateFromProps` is probably not the right choice for your problem at all.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, If myState is an array then directly checking `props.myPropsState !== state.prevPropsState` will fail, You either need to compare the array deeply or use immutable list

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Using a new `key` (or an `id` if the component is expensive to re-initialize) passed from the parent should be used, to allow for reseting the state from the parent by passing new props. This is all described [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#preferred-solutions). Deeply comparing objects **before every render** doesn't seem to be a good solution to me.

Comment: @trixn The best way to handle such cases is memoization and using Immutable lists of objects. I will update the answer with more details when I get more time during night

Comment: I don't want to use memoization. Is there any other solution except derivedstate?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, why do you not want to use memoization.

Comment: @Shubham Khatri The best way to re-compute state is memorization. However in this example nothing is computed. So the best and also officially recommended way is to use a `key` or an `id` to signal reset. Or of course you can just make it fullly controlled and let the parent handle updates (most efficient).

Comment: Actually, I need to set myState not that's coming from props but you're setting state differently, In this case, the answer to the problem differs badly. To your answer, I'm comparing array properly. I can think that I shouldn't use derived state. and need to find some solution.

Comment: In the example nothing is computed because whenever component will receive the props I always want that, however tried your suggestion returning null but din't help.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Yeah it's fine, I didn't meant to say you should compute something. But just to repeat myself: If you want to (partially) reset the state of a child by passing new props you should either use a `key` or `id` that you pass and compare if it has changed or entirely lift state up to the parent to let it handle the changes. This is very extensively described in [this official blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) to repeat myself again. Don't know why you refuse to read it.

Answer (score 0):

From the react docs:

> Note that this method is fired **on every render**, regardless of the cause. This is in contrast to `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps`, which only fires when the parent causes a re-render and not as a result of a local `setState`.

You are effectively overriding your state with the current props every time after calling `setState()`. So when you check a box `(e) => this.handleMethod(e, comp.myState)` is called which is assume calls `setState()` to update the checked state of the checkbox. But after that `getDerivedStateFromProps()` will be called (**before render**) that reverts that change. This is why [unconditionally updating state from props is considered an anti-pattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state).