# ReactJS - componentWillReceiveProps uses

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reactive-programming

I started to learn **ReactJS** I would like to know what are the scenario to use **componentWillReceiveProps**? what is the purpose for using it?
Currently i'm using props without it, is there any impact ?

Comment: [The documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) has some uses listed for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases where you want to take action in child component in response to props change, `componentWillReceiveProps` was supposed to the right candidate. Example of it is when you have a user component which calls and API to fetch the user details based on an ID that is provided by its parent and anytime the prop ID changes, you would want to trigger the API call again and re-render the updated view.

However, componentWillReceiveProps is called on every parent re-render and not just prop change, so while you are using it, you must provide a conditional check between previous and currentProps like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if(nextProps.id !== this.props.id) {
       //API call goes here
   }
}
```

However from v16 onwards, its discouraged to use `componentWillReceiveProps` and instead its usage is split into `componentDidUpdate` which is where you can make API calls and `getDerivedStateFromProps or memoized  functions or key updates` in order to make state change based on prop change.

Please check [`componentWillReceiveProps vs getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671593/componentwillreceiveprops-vs-getderivedstatefromprops/51671750#51671750) for more details

Answer (score 1):

If your component accept some props and if on change of that props you would like to do some business logic or state change, `componentWillReceiveProps` is the lifecycle method where this logic should go, as every time props changes `componentWillReceiveProps` is called.